# Add watermark, set bitrate and scale video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm looking for the command to edit a video with ffmpeg according to instructions below.

The original video can be any type in any size or resolution (mp4,avi,wmv etc) and needs to be converted to mp4

- Convert video to .mp4
- Add a watermark at the right bottom
- Set a Bitrate (accepted values between 1500 - 2000 )
- Resize width to 1280px (keep aspect ratio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic command is:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=1280:-2[bg];[bg][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" -b:v 1500k output.mp4
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.
When mentioning "basic", would you rather advice to add something to optimize?

Comment: @razz Sure. `overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:format=auto,format=yuv420p` may improve the look of the overlay. Adding `-movflags +faststart` output option is worth adding. Makes playback start faster in some situations. Using [two-pass encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass) is highly recommended when targeting a specific bitrate (otherwise, just use `-crf`). You can [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio (`-c:a copy`) if it is AAC audio instead of re-encoding it.